# How do I make Mathematica to always evaluate Log[0, x] as Power[0, x]?

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra

So, sometimes Mathematica cannot evaluate the base-0 logarithm of certain matrices.

But we know that the expressions $0^x$ and $\log_0 x$ are always equivalent.
What can I do so that Mathematica always would interpret `Log[0, x]` as `0^x`? For instance, `Log[0, 0]=1`, but not only that.

Another example,

`MatrixFunction[Log[0, #]&, {{1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}]`

should give result `{{1/2,-1/2},{-1/2,1/2}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work:

```
Unprotect[Power]; Power[0, 0] = 1; Protect[Power];
Unprotect[Log]; Log[0, x_] = Power[0, x]; Protect[Log];
```